# Как использовать два одинаковых javascript на одной странице?

Tags: javascript

Использую две разные формы на одной странице. Для каждой формы должна работать своя функция умножения.

```js
let arg = document.querySelector('input[name="argument"]');
let res = document.querySelector('input[name="result"]');
let cur = document.querySelector('select');
let arr = [arg, cur];

let calc = () => res.value = arg.value * cur.value;
arr.forEach(function(el){
 el.addEventListener('input', calc);
});
calc();

let arg2 = document.querySelector('input[name="argument2"]');
let res2 = document.querySelector('input[name="result2"]');
let cur2 = document.querySelector('select');
let arr2 = [arg2, cur2];

let cal2 = () => res2.value = arg2.value * cur2.value;
arr.forEach(function(el){
 el.addEventListener('input', calc);
});
calc();
```

```html
<input type="number" name="argument" value="2"/>
<input type="text" name="result"/>
<select name="currency">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>2</option>
  <option value="3" >3</option>
</select>

<input type="number" name="argument2" value="2"/>
<input type="text" name="result2"/>
<select name="currency2">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>2</option>
  <option value="3" >3</option>
</select>
```

В первой форме все работает корректно, но я не могу создать такую же функцию для второй формы на одной странице из-за недостаточного знания синтаксиса.

Как корректно указать функцию умножения для второй формы?

Comment: указанные инпуты и селекты лежат в разных формах? добавь разметку с формами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых у вас `select` один на всех:

```
 let cur = document.querySelector('select');
```

добавьте ему уникальный id, например, ну или как вы уже делали name.

```
 let cur2 = document.querySelector('select[name="currency2"]');
```

Конечно, все рекомендуют использовать id:

```
let cur2 = document.querySelector('select#myId');
```

Во-вторых вы переименовали `calc` и `arr` в `cal2` и `arr2`, но не везде, поэтому возникла путаница.

```
 arr2.forEach(function(el){
```

и

```
 let cal2 =...
```

```js
let arg = document.querySelector('input[name="argument"]');
let res = document.querySelector('input[name="result"]');
let cur = document.querySelector('select[name="currency"]');
let arr = [arg, cur];

let calc = () => res.value = arg.value * cur.value;
arr.forEach(function(el){
 el.addEventListener('input', calc);
});
calc();

let arg2 = document.querySelector('input[name="argument2"]');
let res2 = document.querySelector('input[name="result2"]');
let cur2 = document.querySelector('select[name="currency2"]');
let arr2 = [arg2, cur2];

let cal2 = () => res2.value = arg2.value * cur2.value;
arr2.forEach(function(el){
 el.addEventListener('input', cal2);
});
cal2();
```

```html
<input type="number" name="argument" value="2"/>
<input type="text" name="result"/>
<select name="currency">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>2</option>
  <option value="3" >3</option>
</select>

<input type="number" name="argument2" value="2"/>
<input type="text" name="result2"/>
<select name="currency2">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>2</option>
  <option value="3" >3</option>
</select>
```